# How to have a htaccess catch all rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a series of rewirtes to view and process a message center:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/process/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ messages-process.php?do=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/process/ajax/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ messages-process.php?do=$1&ajax=true [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/view/([0-9]+)/?$ messages.php?page=view&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ messages.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/?$ messages.php [L]
```

My question is, how can I setup a rule that will serve as a catch all, so if someone browses to `/messages/process/` they will still end up on messages-process.php but without the required parameters set.

Another way of looking at it, is how can I make the parameters optional, to where the rewrite will still work, but the parameters will be missing?

Comment: Should the rule apply *only* to `/messages/process/`? Your rule for `^messages/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$` matches this already.

Comment: I would like to understand what both solutions would look like. I have many other rewrite rules, so I would like to understand how to accomplish, not just a direct answer. An explanation of both with example code would be best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The your request to `/messages/process/` is matched by this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ messages.php?page=$1 [L]
```

... so you will need a more specific rule which matches `/messages/process/` earlier and routes it to `messages-process.php` before matching the more generic rule.

Placing this *before* all your other rules would accomplish it for that specific pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/process/?$ messages-process.php [L]
```

If you have other directories besides `process/` which would need a similar rewrite, like `/messages/thing` to `messages-thing.php`, use this rule *before* your others. You will need to explicitly list those that should not be matched by the more generic rule later on...

```
# Matches /messages/process/ or /messages/otherdirectory/, etc...
RewriteRule ^messages/(process|thing|otherdirectory|somethingelse)/?$ messages-$1.php [L]
```

All together, this should do the job:

```
# Matches /messages/process/ or /messages/otherdirectory/, etc...
RewriteRule ^messages/(process|thing|otherdirectory|somethingelse)/?$ messages-$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/process/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ messages-process.php?do=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/process/ajax/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ messages-process.php?do=$1&ajax=true [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/view/([0-9]+)/?$ messages.php?page=view&id=$1 [L]
# Stuff not matched by the specific rule at the top matches this one...
RewriteRule ^messages/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ messages.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/?$ messages.php [L]
```

#### Update:

To allow for a URL like `/messages/process/trash` to be rewritten generically, you would need a rule just after this one:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/process/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ messages-process.php?do=$1&id=$2 [L]
# Match stuff after /process/whatever which are not followed by digits (which the previous rule matches)
RewriteRule ^messages/process/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(?:/[^0-9]+/?)$ messages-proces.php [L]
```

Comment: What of a user visits `messages/process/trash/` then I am getting a 'not found' error?

Comment: @ATLChris That wasn't one of your stated criteria. That would require a rule like `RewriteRule ^messages/process(?:/([^0-9]+))? messages-process.php [L]` to be matched instead of the one with the `[0-9]+`.